# Upgrade TypeScript Version + Extraneous error

Tags: typescript, npm

On running npm ls typescript on my SharePoint project, I get an extraneous error. How do I fix that?

[image]
Also, current typescript version is 2.4.2. I tried upgrading it to 3.1.6 by running:

npm i typescript@3.1.6 -g. However I still see version 2.4.2 on running npm ls typescript. Please let me know how I can upgrade typescript to latest version

Comment: Please provide [any errors or log information as text, not as an image](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).